# bootstrap slider img size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

Hello everyone i started just new to learn bootstrap i did a website with bootstrap 4 and i added a slide but photos does not fill all page although i wrote height:100; weight:100; in css and i tried height:auto; and weight:auto; but sizes of photos are different how can i solve it and photo sizes are different.

Comment: Add your html and css codes to the post so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your height and with (not 'weight') with **100%** (take notice of the percatage). So your css would look like this:

```
.some-class
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively you can use bootstraps predefined class `w-100`. Here's an example with the predefined class:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="First slide">
</div>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/JwDYHaSMFy)